# SwiftUI ScrollView Refreshable doesn't work appropriately

Tags: ios, swiftui, scrollview, refreshable

I'm developing in iOS version 16.0 and I have an issue with refreshing scrollview within SwiftUI. I want to refresh and reload data for ScrollView from CoreData, and the ScrollView Code is written like this.

```swift
ScrollView {
    Spacer()
        .frame(height: 50)
    
    ForEach(viewModel.insightList, id: \.self) { insightData in
        InsightListCardView(viewModel: InsightListCardViewModel(insight: insightData))
    }
}
.refreshable {
    viewModel.getInsightList()
}
```

And the function `getInsightList()` is calling only one function, which is below.

```
func getAllInsights() -> [InsightData] {
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<InsightData> = InsightData.fetchRequest()
    let result = try? context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        
    return result?.reversed() ?? []        
}
```

And the problem is here. When I try to refresh the scrollview with pulling, the content of scrollview is moving down. The start position of scroll Indicator is also moving down, but not the entire scrollview height is decreased, so scrolling up is available.

The strange part is here. When I check the view hierarchy, only the screen is moved and the actual components are stay in the appropriate position. Buttons work not when I click the position on the screen, but when I click the original position.

[simulator screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0Fwg.jpg)

Comment: You have to empty your insightList before refreshing.

Comment: I tried that, but emptying data doesn't help me. though, thank you for answering.

Answer (score 0):

For a workaround you can try scrolling up as the

```
.refreshable
```

block triggers, by using

```
ScrollViewReader
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).